# Best way for definie sizes (font-size, margin, padding,..) in jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am working on a jquery mobile website which should also look nice with retina displays.

Now, I am wondering which unit or way is the best, for defining sizes/distances like padding, margin, font-size and so on?

If I use pixel, I wouldn't look good in the different screen resolutions. Whats the common way?

Comment: I normally use percentages. Use one display to play around with your percentages. Once you are satisfied with your results you will have a set of final percentages, then try on other displays and resolutions.

Comment: but there is the problem with icons / csssprites. how do you handle this?

Comment: you could use background-size